# Login Form error in Spring Security

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am writing a Login Controller for my web app which is developed using Spring. I have already developed RegisterController and it's working, but I am not able to login with any of the user. I am also using Spring Security to check security credentials.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--FOR THE UTF-8 CHARACTER ENCODING-->
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- Creating Database Connection here -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bupanoDb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.bupano</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000" />
</bean>

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addPost/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/addPost/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="userEmail"
        password-parameter="userPassword" />
    <security:logout
        logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT userEmail, authority FROM AUTHORITIES WHERE userEmail = ?"
                                    users-by-username-query="SELECT userEmail, userPassword, isActive FROM USER WHERE userEmail = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

here is login.jsp view:

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>

<div id="page">
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns"></div>
        <div class="four columns">

            <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
            </c:if>
            <form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/> " method="POST">
                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
                </c:if>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="userEmail">E-Posta</label>
                    <input id="userEmail" type="email" class="form-control" name="userEmail" placeholder="E-Posta Adresinizi Girin" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="userPassword">Şifre</label>
                    <input id="userPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" placeholder="Şifrenizi Girin" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-control">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send-message pull-right">GİRİŞ</button>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And lastly, here is the LoginController:

```
package com.bupano.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestParam (value = "error", required = false) String error,
                        @RequestParam (value = "logout", required = false) String logout, Model model) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Yanlış kullanıcı adı veya şifre");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Başarılı bir şekilde çıkış yaptınız");

    return "login";
}
}
```

Whenever I try to login, I always get `error` as "", which means not null. Because of that, it always getting into "**Yanlış kullanıcı adı veya şifre**", which is "**Wrong username or password**". Wherever I look in the internet, they always did this login form pages and controllers like this, here is the another example:https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.bupano</groupId>
<artifactId>bupano</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistance</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Photo upload-->
    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- It is better to have below 3 ones at the end of the pom file -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problems root cause with more and more debugging. For those who experiences the same problem, here is the answer.

When I wrote my **User** model, I generated my *getters* and *setters* automatically with the help of *intelliJ*. Apparently, t is having some problems to autogenerate some boolean variable's getter and setter functions.

I have an **isActive** variable in my **User** model to check if the user is still active or not.

Normally, I was expecting to see it's setter as below:

```
public void setActive (boolean active) {
    this.isActive = active;
}
```

but instead of that, I've seen that the code end up like below:

```
public void setActive (boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
}
```

So when it comes to end, it automatically added ***false*** to my **isActive** check in all users, and because of that, application doesn't allow **non-active** user to login.